# PostgreSQL Convert column from integer to text

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL (9.0) database with a column card_id which is currently of type integer

I need to change this to type text

What is the most best way to achieve this?

The only solution I can find involves creating a temporary column, dropping the original then renaming, I thought they might be a better method??

Comment: Text columns take up different amounts of space on the disk.  You can't just make that space mean something different.  Even in RDBMS that have a GUI to allow "just change the type", behind the scenes a new column is created and the original removed.

Comment: ok so what you are saying is I have to create a new column? ta

Comment: Why you can. Behind the scenes happens something monstrous, but it's on the server side, anyway.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Have you tried what the fine manual [suggests](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN anycol TYPE anytype;
```

Depending on the current and the new type you may need to add `USING ...` to this statement.
But in your specific case that should not be necessary I believe.

Comment: IIRC older versions didn't support

Comment: This method works great most of the time, but testing it always helps to insure it will work well under your work load.  Let's say you have 40 trillion rows. With this solution won't it go after all the rows in one transaction?  In that case you may want to batch up the amount of rows that the data type change will go after at a time. To do that you would want a temp column and or table to process the data in batches.

Comment: altering a column type like this is implemented as a table rewrite, not even an attempt to update the table data inplace. so yes, it will take some considerable time and disk space for a large table. users have to make their own decision about the relative merits of a more complicated transition.

Comment: To you sir, I tip my hat

Answer (score 13):

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN card_id SET DATA TYPE text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting an existing numeric column to boolean (faced this issue during oracle to postgreSQL migration), dropping and enabling default constraint too:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
    ALTER COLUMN column_name DROP DEFAULT,
    ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE BOOLEAN 
         USING (case when column_name =1 then true else false end)::BOOLEAN,
    ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DEFAULT false;
```

Comment: And how does this answer the "integer to text" question asked in the post?