# Alter Table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm facing an issue in PostgreSQL. I try do alter column and drop int to amend it to a varchar (50). For some reason I'm still getting an error message: syntax error at or near integer. Is it possible to modify a table with Alter function from int to varchar right?

I set: alter table discount
alter column discount drop integer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL Convert column from integer to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343286/postgresql-convert-column-from-integer-to-text) Using google before creating a question here is not that complicated, is it?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the SQL statement you are running (as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)) and the exact and complete error message you get.

Comment: I was finally able to amend it. Can I ask you what is the difference between 
alter table alter column (column_name) set
VS alter table alter column (column_name) type? I was able to modify it by using type but not getting it why

Comment: Using set, or drop modifies the constraints, and type modifies the date type? is it right?